# Different developer name for app in play store

Tags: android, google-play

Our company has a developer account in the google play store, under which we uploaded several apps. Of course, we are listed as the developers of these apps in the play store.

For our new app, the client himself wants to be listed as the developer. Is there any way we could upload the app ourselves, but list our client as developer of this application?

Comment: Can your client not just create his own developer account and you can use that one for his app

Comment: Why not just have the client create the developer account and you can send him the .apk to upload or you can login through it?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that option, that's the way will do it if we can't go with the option I described above. It would just be easier for us to update the stuff this way.

Comment: Been a while since I created a developer account, but isn't there an option to have more than one person/entity have credentials? If that's the case, have the client open an account, and give your company access.

Comment: Did you find any way to do this? i also need to have different developer names for different applications in same client account.

Answer (score 1):

Your client starts his own Google Developer account and then gives your account administrative rights of his account.

Settings -> User accounts & rights in the development console.

When successful you will see an arrow under your developer name in the developer console, and you can switch between accounts with ease.